# rails のパスが上手く通せない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

`rails g controller api/hello --no-assets --no-helper` このコマンドを実行してテスト用のapiを作成したのですが上手くパスが通せないです。

hello_controller.rb

```
class Api::HelloController < ApplicationController

  def show #　ここをindexに変更してnamespace resources　:hello, only:[:index]と記述すると想定通りに動作する。
    render json: "Hello"
  end
end
```

routes.rb
下記のような形でパスを通すことは出来ないのか...

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'api/hello', to: 'hello#show'
  # あるいは
  # get 'password_resets/new' こんな感じでパスを通してるものがあったため
  get 'api/hello/show'
end
```

こちらのパス設定 `get 'api/hello', to: 'hello#show'` で `http://localhost:8888/api/hello` アクセスすると `uninitialized constant HelloController` と出力される。

いまいち resource を使ったメソッドの方法で出来るものは上記のような GET, POSTメソッド等を直接あてて設定出来ない理由が分からないです。
詳しい方教えて頂けないでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

Rails のルーティングでは `namespace` や `scope` を使ってコントローラーに名前空間を作ることができます。この機能を活用すると解決できそうです。

https://railsguides.jp/routing.html#%E3%82%B3%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88%E3%83%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A9%E3%81%AE%E5%90%8D%E5%89%8D%E7%A9%BA%E9%96%93%E3%81%A8%E3%83%AB%E3%83%BC%E3%83%86%E3%82%A3%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0

Answer (score 0):

`get 'api/hello', to: 'api/hello#show'` とすることでパスを通せました。

`get 実際にアクセスを投げるパスを設定する/helloでも好きに設定できる, to: 'コントローラーがある場所を指定するapiフォルダの中にhello_controller.rbがあるなら上記の設定になるそしてファイル内の関数showにアクセスするには#showと指定する。'`